# Como chamar um Service através de outro aplicativo?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Tenho dois aplicativos, o aplicativo 1 tem diversos CRUD, o aplicativo 2 tem diversos services e notificações.

Ao tentar iniciar o Service pelo aplicativo 1, está acontecendo isso:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
>   cmp=com.example.luiz.servicelocation/.LocationService } without
>   permission not exported from uid 10059

Teria como eu iniciar um service do meu aplicativo 2 através de um botão no meu aplicativo 1?

Comment: Nesse Link está bem explicado a forma de se fazer essa comunicação entre apps https://web.archive.org/web/20130731024012/http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/InterAppCommunication

Comment: Esta acontecendo isso: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.luiz.servicelocation/.LocationService } without permission not exported from uid 10059

Comment: Acho que funcionou, essa configuração <service
            android:name=".LocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

Comment: @LuizLanza Publique sua solução como resposta para facilitar a vida de quem tiver o mesmo problema no futuro.

Comment: Solução igual ao @jdoper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro olhe seu AndroidManifest.xml e copie o conteúdo dentro de package, no caso "com.example.pedro.aplicativo".

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pedro.aplicativo" ></manifest>
```

Na sua activity use o código abaixo, na variável pacote coloque o que você copiou de package (com.example.pedro.aplicativo) e na variável coloque o nome da classe do service que você quer chamar (com.example.pedro.aplicativo.MeuServico).

```
import android.content.ComponentName;

Intent intent = new Intent();
String pacote = "com.example.pedro.aplicativo";
String classe = "com.example.pedro.aplicativo.MeuServico";
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pacote, classe));
startService(intent);
```